# AJAX request to PHP file on login page

Tags: php, ajax

I've stumbled across a problem with AJAX requests in PHP and I haven't been able to find a topic that is close to what I've already wrote in my code.

To start off, I want to create a login page for my web app using AJAX requests to a PHP file.

In "login.php":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $errorWrapper = $('#error-handler'); // Error div 
        var $errorCardText = $('#error-handler p'); // Error div text
        var $user = $('#user-input'); // Input field for username
        var $pwd = $('#pwd-input'); // Input field for password

        $('#login-btn').on('click', function(){

            var $data = {
            'username': $user.val(),
            'password': $pwd.val()
            };

            $dataStr = JSON.stringify($data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/loginValid.php',
                data: {json: $dataStr}, 
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Success");
                    if(data.status == 0){
                        $errorWrapper.css('display', 'block');
                        $errorCard.text("Username or password incorrect!");
                    }else if (data.status == 2){
                        $errorWrapper.css('display', 'block');
                        $errorCard.text("No matching account for username inserted.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

In "loginValid.php" (it's the file that's catching the POST request from AJAX):

```
<?php
include 'classes.php';

//Catch the AJAX POST request form server and decode it from JSON

    $request = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
    $username = $request['username'];
    $password = $request['password'];

    $loginObj = new LoginValid($username, $password);
    $code = $loginObj -> checkValidation();

    $response = array('status' => $code);

    echo json_encode($response));?>
```

The "classes.php" file implements the function for checking the credentials:

```
class LoginValid{
    private $username;
    private $pwd;
    private $statusCode;

    function __construct($user, $pass){
        $this->$username = $user;
        $this->$pwd = hash('sha512', $pass);
    }

    public function checkValidation (){

        include '../conf/db.php';

        $conn = new mysqli($servernameDB, $userDB, $passwordDB, $dbName);

        $stmt = $conn -> prepare ("SELECT FROM users WHERE username = ?");

        $stmt -> bind_param('s', $this->$username);

        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $result = $stmt -> get_result();
        $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

        // Check if the credentials match and return the status code for jQuery error handler

        if ($result -> num_rows == 0){
            $this->$statusCode = 2;
        }else{

            if ($row['username'] == $this -> $username && $row['password'] == $this->$pwd){
                $this -> $statusCode = 1;
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                header("Location: ../index.php");
            }else{
                $this -> $statusCode = 0;
            }
        }

        return $this -> $statusCode;
    }
}
```

"db.php" stores just the database credentials for easier integration throughout the application.

I can't figure out why it's not entering the success callback. I mention the fact that I've already tried to alert the JSON string before making the AJAX request and it's showing the correct thing.

Thank you.

Comment: First... add an error handler. If it isn't reaching the success callback, it is either reaching the error callback, or the page is reloading before the request finishes. Error handling is a rather important tool that is ignored far too often.

Comment: @KevinB Indeed, I added the error callback and it's reaching it. Though, I have no clue why.

Comment: What error message does it give you? i suspect "parseerror"

Comment: @KevinB Using xhr, it gives two errors: first one - Undefined index 'json' in loginValid.php  - the second one  - Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in classes.php.

Comment: edit them into your question

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

When you use an object as the `data:` option in `$.ajax`, it uses URL-encoded format, not JSON. The fact that the value of the `json` parameter is JSON is not relevant, it's still wrapped in a URL-encoded parameter. You should leave out that option.

It would be even simpler if you just did:

```
data: $data,
```

Then in the PHP script you can use `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`, you don't need to call `json_decode()`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much, I've been trying to figure this out for hours since I'm new in AJAX.

Comment: I'm curious why you thought the contentType was needed, since I doubt you would have see it in many tutorial examples.

Comment: Because I thought that once you pass the data in json format to php file, it is necessary to include contentType, but obviously it was wrong.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you thought that, since you would never have seen it in any examples that you copied from.